# ReactJs webpack hot reloading

Tags: reactjs, webpack

I am new to ReactJS and trying to create a smooth dev environment. I have started from scratch without boilerplates, i get down well till **hot reloading**.

First, what I've found was [Dan Abramov's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/458193/dan-abramov) [hot reloading approach](https://github.com/gaearon/react-hot-boilerplate).
It adds a few options to webpack.config.js and a server.js file in which a beginner is not familiar with. This setups server-browser hot reloading connection very well.

However, when i install the boilerplate of [ReactJS hello world](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/installation.html#creating-a-single-page-application), it also runs with hot reloading process but, i see that there is not any server.js and there is no even a webpack.config.js file. (*There is `react-scripts` script in package.json. I guess this script handles all the webpack and hot reloading configuration.*)

So i wonder if there is or will be a standard way of hot reloding in react+webpack environment. Or which ways above should i stick to?

Comment: Hey, the way creating server.js and run it with npm script from packages file its the preferrd way.

Answer (score 0):

the way creating server.js and run it with npm script from packages file its the preferrd way.

you should add at packages file something like this:
json object

> {
>            "start": "babel-node tools/server.js"
>       }

then you can use npm start

and you should have  - **server.js** file which includes all the app server initalizition etc:

```
const app = express();
const compiler = webpack(config);
app.use(require('webpack-hot-middleware')(compiler));
```

hope it help you, hod

Comment: for the moment, i am sticking to [hot relaoding package](https://github.com/gaearon/react-hot-boilerplate), i think it is the same way with this.